# Selected option for ruby nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, select

I have a form

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Customer Name", class: 'form-control'%>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Address1</td>
    <td>Address2</td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>Zip</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <%= f.fields_for :customer_addresses do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'customer_addresses/table_form', f: builder  %>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= link_to_add_fields 'Add Field', f, :customer_addresses %>

<br/><br/>
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default"  %>
```

with a nested form (customer_addresses/table_form)

```
<tr>
  <td><%= f.text_field :address1, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Address 1' %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :address2, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Address 2' %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :city, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'City' %></td>
  <td><%= f.select :state, options_for_select(us_states), class: 'form-control' %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :zip, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Zip' %></td>
  <td><%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %><%= link_to 'remove', '#', class: 'remove_fields' %></td>
</tr>
```

and all works great and renders the form nicely. But when the `select` for the `:state` field gets rendered in the edit window, it is always Alabama (the first state that the `us_states` helper function exports.) What would I add to `f.select` so that the selected state in the customer address is rendered with the selected option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to use `options_for_select` with `select` (only with `select_tag`) because `select` does that for you if you just pass the same argument you are passing to `options_for_select`.

So, you'd have to do something like:

```
f.select :state, us_states #, etc
```

I'm assuming that `:state` is not an association, if it is then it should be `:state_id`